# How can I create a WCF service that allows users to connect to my service through a web browser and upload a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I've created a Hello World WCF service that uses the ASP.NET Development Server - I launch the client which opens a page in my web browser, HelloWorldService.svc, then this triggers the command prompt to open and print out a Hello World message.

I don't fully understand this chain of action or how it's useful.

I'm trying to create a WCF service that acts as a server that allows users to connect to the server and perform a file upload - I will take this file and store it locally on my machine.

For now, allowing this to work locally on only my PC is fine but I really don't know where to begin to accomplish this. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: I NEED to use WCF. So please don't suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is arguably overkill.  Simplest case, just use the standrad .Net [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

Here are some examples:

- [ASP.NET File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167240/asp-net-file-upload)
- http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Which leads to the question "When should I use WCF"?  Here are a couple of answers:

- [When & where I should use WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615194/when-where-i-should-use-wcf)
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1480028.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512038.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1478962.aspx

Finally, here are a couple of links that describe WCF-based file transfer services:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2

Comment: I know but I need to use the Microsoft Interop PowerPoint servers to manipulate some PPTs after upload so I have to use WCF (I believe).

Comment: Fair enough - updated post with additional info.  FYI, you can also adopt a "hybrid" approach: WCF communications and simple HTTP interactions can both reside on the same web server.

Comment: Do you know of any sources that could take me through the entire process from start to finish leaving out no details? I'm very new to WCF and although these both look like great tutorials, it seems they expect knowledge of the basics of WCF which I haven't yet quite grasped. Thank you.

Comment: EDIT: If not that's fine, I've downloaded the source code from the first article and I'll make the best of it. NEVER MIND - I DON'T KNOW ENOUGH TO MAKE USE OF THIS SOURCE CODE. I was expecting it to be an entire VS project but it's not.