# Is it possible to create a website with WCF?

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to create a website (hosted locally on my machine is fine for now) using a WCF Service Application?

By "web site" I mean allow an HTTP call from a web browser to my service and have the service return an HTML page that the browser can then render/display.

Comment: That's not what WCF is intented for. You're looking for ASP.Net.

Comment: Mmn you can probably return HTML as a string, nothing can stop you.. but not a good idea. You'd want to return data instead. You can also check out WebApi.. could help

Comment: Well the reason I want to use WCF is because I need to use the Microsoft Interop Services and I was under the impression they won't work for ASP.Net. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TonyFriz can you elaborate on your last comment / what you're trying to do?  Interop services should work equally well on WCF / ASP.Net, as both sit on top of the .Net runtime + IIS.

Comment: @McGarnagle I'm trying to convert a PPT file to a video file and allow mobile applications to connect to my server, upload their PPT, then download it as a video file. You're saying I can do this with just ASP.NET? I guess I could accept a POST request with the PPT attached and then send back a video file, right?

Comment: I think you're confused.  IIS (a Microsoft web server) and WCF (a Microsoft framework for exposing and consuming software components) are *COMPLEMENTARY* technologies.  You can have *BOTH* ... and mix'n'match the two however suits your needs.  1) Getting the files from the user is a good job for ASP.Net.  2) Manipulating the files  can easily be done from WCF (if need be), simply by modifying one of your existing WCF services.  IMHO...

Comment: And yes, of *COURSE* System.Runtime.InteropServices can be used from ASP.Net.  These APIs can be used from *ANY* .Net program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a WCF service that allows users to connect to my service through a web browser and upload a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283961/how-can-i-create-a-wcf-service-that-allows-users-to-connect-to-my-service-throug)

Answer (score 3):

I am doing something very similar using a WCF based REST service. I have a WCF service that is accessed only from a web browser to download images. If you browse to 'http://www.MyFooImageService.com/100', it will lookup from the database an image with ID 100 and serve it up to the user. I use it to serve images from WCF service for the purpose of sending (user defined) emails with embedded images.

I used this guide with great results: [RESTFUL WCF Service Step-ByStep](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide/). Check it out and see if a REST based WCF service is what you are looking for.

Comment: See also [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2), cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283961/how-can-i-create-a-wcf-service-that-allows-users-to-connect-to-my-service-throug/19284042).

Comment: I believe that RESTful WCF is deprecated in favor of ASP.Net WebAPI.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't quite work like that. WCF applications are service applications. There is no GUI interface or web interface or any kind of interface at all.

What you do is you create a WCF service that does some sort of function. Lets say you create a method called `StoreName` that stores your name into a database. Keep it simple. WCF services can be hosted in a variety of ways, depending on how you plan to use it. But to keep it simple, lets say you host the application using IIS.

Now this WCF application has no interface for interacting with it. You need to create an ASP.NET application (or it can be PHP, or jQuery if you prefer). It might have a text box and a submit button. Once the submit button is pushed, the ASP.NET application (or jQuery or PHP) makes an ajax call to your WCF service, passing it in the name as a POST parameter. The WCF service then does the work of storing it in the database. Execution then returns back to your web application.

This is a general overview of how this works. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm. I've been developing website with PHP for many years so I guess maybe that's why this isn't clicking for me. The thing is, I need to use the Microsoft Interop PowerPoint services for manipulating PPT files and I was under the impression that this is no possible with ASP.NET. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @TonyFriz -- How you would do this is you would create a WCF Service application that contains methods to do what it is you need to do. For example, you might have a method called `RemoveSlide(int slideNum)` and you would write your code that removes a slide using the PowerPoint Interop. Once you have this, you would use PHP (or ASP.NET) to call that RemoveSlide function. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that does make sense - I guess my next question then is how can I set this up? How exactly would I make a call to this RemoveSlide() function from an ASP.NET website? What would I include from my WCF service so that making a call to this method is understood and doesn't error? Is there any walk-throughs you know of that covers exactly this?

Comment: Microsoft has a [good tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) on how to create a WCF Service. There is also a [good tutorial on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows) for creating WCF services.

Comment: @TonyFriz - Just as a side note, before you tackle this project, make sure WCF is right for your needs. You can call the PowerPoint Interop methods directly from ASP.NET without needing WCF at all. The only reason to use WCF in your case if you need to manipulate the PowerPoint PPT files from a non .NET language (such as PHP) or if you plan to create, for example, a mobile application for manipulating PPT files.

Comment: Damn - I DO need to create a mobile application for this. But couldn't I just make a POST call from the mobile application to the ASP.NET page that does the manipulating and then send back what needs to be sent back?

Comment: Technically, yes. But its not the correct way, and in fact, its more cumbersome in my opinion. In addition, you'd have to have an ASP.NET website running at all times that does nothing except wait for a POST from your mobile application. In addition, if the website went down for some reason, so would your mobile application. Finally, if you do have a website running that can manipulate PPT files, there is also an issue of security. What would keep a hacker from simply using a tool such as Fiddler to make their own POST to your web server?

Comment: OK - how would this change if I used ASP.NET and WCF? Wouldn't I still need an ASP.NET page always running waiting for my mobile application to make a request and then from there call the WCF function? I'm sorry I'm just so very confused.

Comment: An ASP.Net page (or, for that matter, a PHP page) is the best way to interact with the user.  So yes, you'd need the page "always running".  But that *DOESN'T* mean you need to accomplish everything entirely in WCF.  Nor does it mean you necessarily need another server.  ALSO: I think you might be confused about the "Services" part of "Interop.Services" you're using for PowerPoint.  It has nothing directly to do with WCF - it's just a .Net library; accessible from any .Net technology.  Including from ASP.Net.

Comment: So the best way then would to build an ASP.NET page and accept POST requests with a PPT attached, do what I need to with it, then give it back to the user, right? Also, I didn't think because of the word "Services" that it has to be used with WCF - I just thought I read somewhere that the Interop services can't be used with an ASP.NET page - in fact I'm pretty sure I read that from multiple sources. I guess they were wrong though.

Comment: @TonyFriz -- WCF can be [hosted several different ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx). In addition to having it run as an ASP.NET application, you can also host it in a Windows Service. Doing it this way would not require an ASP.NET page to be running nor would it even require ASP.NET at all. It can also  run as a console app if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

A website involves:

**1) A user requesting HTML from somewhere**
You can proxy pass a simple HTTP Get request to a `WCF` service hosted in a console app (or hosted in `IIS`), and configure it to return an HTTP request of content type `text/html`. Then the user would see a website appear in the browser.

But `WCF` is not a good fit for this. Especially if it's a simple HTML page. Others have said `ASP.NET` is better for this. And that's true. But `node.js` or `PHP` or pretty much anything that isn't `.NET` is **MUCH** better for this.

**2) A user uses the web page to interact with server processes**
This involves a user clicking a button or moving a mouse, or anything, and then that results in the web page (actually a web app at this point) making AJAX requests to one, or several server(s).

WCF is quite a good fit for this.